# Network Subscription does not change view immadiately

Tags: cordova, ionic2, observable

I'm using the Network native plugin to detect the network status (connected or not) and to detect a change in network status (onConnect and onDisConnect).

I want to disable some buttons when the network disconnects and also want to enable them when I have the connection back. Therefore the Network plugin has 2 functions called onConnect and onDisConnect which are returning a Observable. in the subscription of these functions, I want to change a class variable called "isConnected". The Code below shows I want to manage this.

```
    ...    
    constructor(...){
        ....
        // network
        this.isConnected            = Network.connection !== "none";
        this.connectSubscription    = Network.onConnect().subscribe(()=>{
          this.updateConnection();
          Toast.showShortBottom("connected now !").subscribe();
        });
        this.disconnectSubscription = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(()=>{
          this.updateConnection();
          Toast.showShortBottom("disconnected now !").subscribe();
        });
    }

    updateConnection(){
      this.isConnected = Network.connection !== "none";
    }
```

and my html file contains some buttons which have to enabled/disabled depending on the connection status "isConnected"..

```
...
      <button ion-button icon-only [disabled]="!isConnected" (click)="openModal()" shortVibrateOnTap>
        <ion-icon ios="ios-swap" md="ios-swap"></ion-icon>
      </button>
...
  <ion-col width-10>
    <button ion-button icon-only class="arrow-btn" [disabled]="!isConnected && onLastQuestion" (click)="fireSth()" shortVibrateOnTap>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="!onLastQuestion" ios="ios-arrow-forward" md="ios-arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="onLastQuestion"  ios="ios-arrow-dropright-circle-outline" md="ios-arrow-dropright-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-col>
...
```

now the onConnect and onDisConnect function firing, But my buttons does not get disabled immadiately ... I first have to tap a button or do another action ... How can I force the view to update the button status ?????

running ionic 2 rc 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ApplicationRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ApplicationRef-class.html) seems to do the trick see [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/subscription-does-not-change-view-immadiately/67212). But I still don't get why this happens ..